# Disable author profile in post

Tags: posts

I am managing a WP 3.0.4 site where every post has the profile of the author appended. Where is the setting to disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no exact "setting" in the backend/Admin UI. You'll have to edit your template files (the php files that are in your theme folder). Search for something like `<a href=""></a>` where you got one (or more) of the php (wp native) function or variable:

- `the_author_posts_link();`
- `$curauth->user_url;`
- `get_the_author();`
- `get_author_posts_url();`
- ... or something theme specific

Helpful is always a link to the download of your theme or some template code.

Comment: It can also be added via hook, so `functions.php` is also worth checking.

Comment: Yep. Just fishing in the dark... ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting! But I found the offending section and hacked it out after all. It was just the standard Twenty-Ten theme that ships with WP 3.